# Using in_array for value in array with key names

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I dont know why but I had a code which checked an array to see if it had the value insde the array already. This to only save the array one time. Here is the code:

```
$categoryatributesarray = [];

$categoryarray['type_name'] =  'NA';
$categoryarray['type_id'] = 'NA';
$categoryarray['value_name'] = 'NA';
$categoryarray['value_id'] = 'NA';
$categoryarray['shopify_type'] = 'NA';
array_push($categoryatributesarray, $categoryarray);  

foreach ($CategoriesMerging as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value['CategoriesMerging']['category_id'])) {
        $this->redirect('/product_mercado_libres/categoryMerging');
        return false;
    }
    $categoryatributes = $meli->get('/categories/' . $value['CategoriesMerging']['category_id'] . '/attributes');
    if (!empty($categoryatributes['body'])) {
        foreach ($categoryatributes['body'] as $key1 => $value1) {
            foreach ($value1->values as $key2 => $value2) {
                if (!in_array($value2->id, $categoryatributesarray)) {
                    $categoryarray['type_name'] =  $value1->name;
                    $categoryarray['type_id'] = $value1->id;
                    $categoryarray['value_name'] = $value2->name;
                    $categoryarray['value_id'] = $value2->id;
                    $categoryarray['shopify_type'] = $value['CategoriesMerging']['type'];
                    array_push($categoryatributesarray, $categoryarray);   
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($categoryatributesarray);
echo '</pre>';
```

The array it gives me and what is looking into is the next:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type_name] => NA
            [type_id] => NA
            [value_name] => NA
            [value_id] => NA
            [shopify_type] => NA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type_name] => Talle
            [type_id] => 30000
            [value_name] => 0-3 M
            [value_id] => 5f95725
            [shopify_type] => Conjuntos
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type_name] => Talle
            [type_id] => 30000
            [value_name] => 3-6 M
            [value_id] => ccbd9f4
            [shopify_type] => Conjuntos
        )
.....
)
```

What Im looking for is for the value_id not to come 2 times in the same array Im printing.

Comment: If you want the `$categoryatributesarray` array to be unique on `value_id`, then you can use `value_id` as the array key as you build `$categoryatributesarray`.

Comment: That is a nice workaround :P Ill use your idea for now. But I would like to know why the way Im building it does not work. What would I have to change on in_array for it to work D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with

```
if (!in_array($value2->id, $categoryatributesarray)) { ...
```

is that `$value2->id` always contains a string, and `$categoryatributesarray` only contains arrays, so that `in_array` will never return true. `in_array` only compares the "needle" against the values in the top level of the "haystack"; it is not a recursive search.

There are different ways to compare `$value2->id` to the `id` column of `$categoryatributesarray`. If you have PHP 5.5+, you can use

```
if (!in_array($value2->id, array_column($categoryatributesarray, 'id'))) { ...
```

the result of `array_column` will be a list of all the `id` attributes of the arrays in `$categoryatributesarray`.

If your PHP version is < 5.5, you could use array_filter instead

```
$id = $value2->id;
$match = array_filter($categoryatributesarray, 
    function($x) use ($id) { return $x->id == $id; });
if (!$match) {
```

I don't know if these are the *"best ways"* to do this. They're just the first ones I thought of.

As I mentioned in the comment, though, I really think either of these methods will not be as efficient as using the `id` as the array key in `$categoryatributesarray` as you build it. Using one of these methods, you will search the entire array each time you add an element to it, and the more elements you add, the more array there is for it to search.

Comment: I didnt thought about the program running through the arrays again and again. Thanks for the other two options :D Ill use the id as key idea you gave me first then. Thanks again for all your help :D